# On the decomposition of topological spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

A topological space $A$ is homotopy dominated by a topological space $X$ is there exist maps $f:X\to A$ and $g:A\to X$ such that $fg\simeq \mathrm{id}_A$.

Clearly, $X$ is homotopy dominated by $X\times Y$ and $X\vee Y$.

For a Moore space $M(G,n)$, $G$ an abelian group and $n\geq 2$, $A$ is homotopy dominated by $M(G,n)$ iff $M(G,n)\simeq A\vee B$ for a space $B$.

For an Eilenberg-MacLane space $K(G,n)$, $G$ a group and $n\geq 1$, $A$ is homotopy dominated by $K(G,n)$ iff $K(G,n)\simeq A\times B$ for a space $B$.

**My question:**  Are  there spaces $X$ (other than Moore or Eilenberg-MacLane spaces) for which $A$ is homotopy dominated by $X$ iff $X\simeq A\times B$ or $X\simeq A\vee B$?

In general, under what condition, if $A$ is homotopy dominated by $X$, then we have $X\simeq A\times B$ or $X\simeq A\vee B$?

Comment: Naive question: What about $(A\vee B)\times C$?